# how do i connect an existing database to sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a database I generated through postgres. How do I connect it to sequelize for node.js?

I know the basic syntax for sequelize connections, but how do I connect these together?

Answer (score 5):

In `node.js` after installing the `sequelize` and `pg` packages through `npm` you can do this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('your_database_name', 'user', 'password', {
  host: "localhost", //your server
  port: 12345 //server port
  dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

Note, in order to use Sequelize with Postgres you'll_need the [postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) package. The [Sequelize homepage](http://www.sequelizejs.com/) contains instructions on changes you might need to make in order to use them together.

Comment: does this database name (for example database.db) have to be in the same directory as the file with the sequelize code?

Comment: No, you need a PostgreSQL server running and you need to connect to it.